# What's the right way to match #includes (or #defines) using Clang's libtooling?

Tags: c++, clang, libtooling

I'm writing a libtooling refactoring tool. I have a class, let's say `Foo`, defined in a header called `foo.h`. I want to see if `foo.h` is included in a file. Currently, to check if `bar.cc` includes `foo.h`, I'm just matching using `recordDecl(hasName("Foo"))`. This works because `class Foo { ... };` will exist inside of `bar.cc`'s AST after preprocessing, if `bar.cc` includes `foo.h`.

But this doesn't work if, for example, `bar.cc` includes `cat.h` which includes `foo.h`. I want `bar.cc` to EXPLICITLY include `foo.h`.

Further, I'd like to be able to match `#define` macros.

The way I've been writing my tool has made these two goals impossible because the AST I'm matching on has already been preprocessed. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? I dug around the `Preprocessor` class reference on Clang's Doxygen pages, but I haven't quite found what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured this out after digging around in Clang's Doxygen and code. I needed to be using the `PPCallbacks` class along with the `Preprocessor` class. An example is below. Note, this isn't guaranteed to be a functional code snippet, but it illustrates general usage. For more info, see Clang's [PPCallbacks](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1PPCallbacks.html) documentation and also the documentation for [addPPCallbacks](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Preprocessor.html#a6290a2d1dda82c6490fff8529f3f5182) and [getPPCallbacks](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Preprocessor.html#a19c49b68d13fbd14b80be6e947bddd4c) in [clang::Preprocessor](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Preprocessor.html).

```
class Find_Includes : public PPCallbacks
{
public:
  bool has_include;

  void InclusionDirective(
    SourceLocation hash_loc,
    const Token &include_token,
    StringRef file_name,
    bool is_angled,
    CharSourceRange filename_range,
    const FileEntry *file,
    StringRef search_path,
    StringRef relative_path,
    const Module *imported)
  {
    // do something with the include
    has_include = true;
  }
};

class Include_Matching_Action : public ASTFrontendAction
{
  bool BeginSourceFileAction(CompilerInstance &ci, StringRef)
  {
    std::unique_ptr<Find_Includes> find_includes_callback(new Find_Includes());

    Preprocessor &pp = ci.getPreprocessor();
    pp.addPPCallbacks(std::move(find_includes_callback));

    return true;
  }

  void EndSourceFileAction()
  {
    CompilerInstance &ci = getCompilerInstance();
    Preprocessor &pp = ci.getPreprocessor();
    Find_Includes *find_includes_callback = static_cast<Find_Includes>(pp.getPPCallbacks());

    // do whatever you want with the callback now
    if (find_includes_callback->has_include)
      std::cout << "Found at least one include" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Comment: This did not work for me, Find_Includes::InclusionDirective() was never executed. But if I inherit from clang::PreprocessOnlyAction instead of ASTFrontendAction then it works. See https://xaizek.github.io/2015-04-23/detecting-wrong-first-include/

Comment: @GerardoHernandez: I just tried this ASTFrontendAction (clang 11) and it works as expected. Maybe a version thing.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully implemented it. I do not think EndSourceFileAction() method should contain anything related to Find_Includes.

```
void InclusionDirective( SourceLocation hash_loc, const Token &include_token, StringRef file_name, bool is_angled, CharSourceRange filename_range,
                            const FileEntry *file, StringRef search_path, StringRef relative_path, const Module *imported)
              {
                  // Add your code here.
              }
bool BeginSourceFileAction(CompilerInstance &CI) 
{     std::unique_ptr<Find_Includes> find_includes_callback(new Find_Includes(TheRewriter));
      Preprocessor &pp = CI.getPreprocessor();
      pp.addPPCallbacks(std::move(find_includes_callback));
      return true;
}
```